# Entity Framework does not contain definition for existing table object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am relatively new to `Entity FrameWork`. I am using the `AdventureWorks Database` as a learning resource. I am also following this tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

My problem is I am unable to insert into multiple tables, specifically two tables:
This is not because an insert is failing but rather the `Object` for the `Person` entity is not available to perform an Add.

The following code adds a new record to the `Person.BusinessEntity` table.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int errorLength = 0;

        using(var dataAccessContext = new DataAccessContext())
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Processing data, please wait...");

                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

                BusinessEntity businessEntity = new BusinessEntity
                {
                    rowguid = guid,
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                };

                dataAccessContext.BusinessEntities.Add(businessEntity);
                dataAccessContext.SaveChanges();

                Console.Clear();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorLength = ex.Message.Trim().Length;

                Console.WriteLine("Data Process Failed:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(errorLength <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Data successfully processed.");
                    Console.Write("Press any key to exit: ");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would also like to create a new person by inserting a record into the Person.Person table. However, the `DataAccessContext()` does not expose the Person object for adding a Person record:

The following does not work:

```
                Person person = new Person
                {
                    BusinessEntityID = Convert.ToInt32(businessID),
                    PersonType = personType,
                    NameStyle = Convert.ToBoolean(nameStyle),
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    MiddleName = middleName,
                    LastName = lastName,
                    EmailPromotion = Convert.ToInt32(emailPromotion),
                    rowguid = guid,
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                };

                dataAccessContext.Person.Add(person);
                dataAccessContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error message:

*DataAccessServices.DataAccessContext' does not contain a definition for 'Person' and no extension method 'Person' accepting a first argument of type 'DataAccessServices.DataAccessContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

Comment: It looks like you are adding the variable `businessEntity` to the `Person` object.  Is that your intention?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo: Copy and Paste error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add the Person definition to the DataAccessContext class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592675.aspx

Or maybe the object already exists as `DataAccessContext.People` or `DataAccessContext.Persons`.  Usually the collection on the data access context is the plural form of the individual model.

Comment: Josh you are correct: the following line was missing from the DataAccessModel.Context.cs file:         `public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }`
I had performed a Database First Model and I am not certain why this was missing. It is working now. More learning. :) Thank you!

Comment: Glad that fixed it! I would highly recommend Pluralsight's training on EF. It will get you up to speed in no time!